# Pass HTTP header user-identifier to Spring SAML2 Security Provider's UserDetailsService

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-saml

I am using `Spring Boot v.1.3.6.RELEASE` with `Spring Security SAML2 v1.0.2.RELEASE`.  I need access to a user identifier from a HTTP header value in my `UserDetailsService` implementation.  This user identifier is set by the reverse proxy and is not the same as the username provided by the user when logging in that comes in the `SAMLCredential`.

The only way that I can figure out to do this is to subclass `SAMLProcessingFilter` and set a `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken` in the security context that I can read later in the `SAMLUserDetailsService`.

```
public class ExtractUsernameFromHttpHeaderSAMLProcessingFilter extends SAMLProcessingFilter {
    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException
    {
        final String nsUserId = request.getHeader("header-name");
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(nsUserId, "******"));
        return super.attemptAuthentication(request, response);
    }
}
```

Then within the `SAMLUserDetailsService` I can read the user identifier.  The `SecurityContext` is updated later with an `ExpiringUsernameAuthenticationToken`.

```
public class SAMLUserDetailsServiceImpl implements SAMLUserDetailsService {
    @Override
    public Object loadUserBySAML(SAMLCredential credential) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        String userIDfromSAML = credential.getNameID().getValue(); // from real user

        final Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        final Object httpUserIdentifier = authentication.getPrincipal();  // from reverse proxy

        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        // add authorities here
        return new User(userIDfromSAML, "********", authorities);
    }
}
```

Although this works, I was wondering if there is a neater/preferred way of doing the same thing?